# Javascript onSubmit Event

Tags: javascript

```
var themes2="dark";     
if(isCanvasSupported()){
            $('#body-wrapper').after('<div id="palette"> \
        <div id="paletteHeader"> \
            <div id="colorResult">#0199FE</div> \
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="closeButton"></a> \
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="openButton"></a> \
        </div> \
    <div id="paletteBody"> \
        <div id="colorPicker"></div> \
        <canvas id="colorPalette" width="150" height="150"></canvas> \
    </div> \
    <div id="ThemeSwitch"> \
        <a class="themeBtn light " href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeTheme(\'light\')">LIGHT</a> \
        <a class="themeBtn dark selected" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeTheme(\'dark\')">DARK</a> \
    </div> \
    <form name="myform" method="post" onSubmit="**return onsubmitform()**;">
    <input type="submit" value="Kaydet"> \
    </form> \
</div>');
```

I coding something.in return onsubmitform() form action make nothing.
onsubmitform function:

```
function onsubmitform()
{
  document.myform.action ="?tasarim="+themes2;
  return true;
}
```

I want something "index.php?tasarim=dark" but browser redirecting only "index.php"...
What can i do for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the method specified in your form is `post` if you want the url to be like `index.php?tasarim=dark` change the `method` in the form to `get`

Comment: has nothing to do with 'get' method.Because I want form action="index.php?tasarim=dark" something.

Answer (score 0):

`themes2` probably isn't defined in the function's scope. Instead, try something like this:

```
......
<form method="post" action="?tasarim='+themes2+'">
```

This eliminates the need for an event handler.

Comment: I tried it.İts successfull.But when themes2 value is change,form action isn't change.

Comment: Well, you could assign an ID to the form (more reliable than `name`), and update its action whenever you update `themes2`.

Comment: I could not understand hardly anything was said by...Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps another way might be to take advantage of jQuery's chaining and instead bind the submit event to that jQuery object you created (vs. inlining it)?